# Uncertainty When Dividing a Constant by a Measurement with Uncertainty

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I am doing a highschool physics experiment in which I am heating springs to different temperatures, measuring their change in extension when subject to the weight force of a mass, and then calculating their spring constant.

In this process, I am finding spring constant from the equation
$mg=kΔx$. However, this requires me to divide mg, a constant in each trial, by $Δx$, a value with uncertainty. I am struggling to figure out what the resulting uncertainty of the value for spring constant is.

E.g: To find k in one trial, I must divide 3.43 N by 0.007 ± 0.001 m. What is the uncertainty of the resultant value? Is the uncertainity given by 3.43/0.001?

Comment: What is stopping you from calculating this?

Comment: I am unsure of the way in which uncertainty should be calculated in this situation. I am struggling to find anything online. I assume the resultant uncertainty is given by the constant divided by the uncertainty of the measurement?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are positive and $a$ is between $x$ and $y$, then $1/a$ is between $1/y$ and $1/x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*However, this requires me to divide $mg$, a constant in each trial, by $Δx$, a value with uncertainty.*

Even though you have kept the mass, $m$, constant whilst doing the experiment it still has an error attached to it as does the gravitational field strength, $g$.
However, in your experiment it looks as though the errors associated with these two quantities are significantly smaller than the error in the extension.

The relationship you are dealing with is $mg = k e$ where $e$ is the extension which you have called $\Delta x$.

Ignoring the error in $mg$ you could value the minimum and maximum value of $k$ consistent with the quoted error in the extension, $k_{\rm max}=\dfrac{3.43}{0.007-0.001}$ and $k_{\rm min}=\dfrac{3.43}{0.007+0.001}$.

A simpler way of evaluating the error is to assume that the error is relatively small and evaluate fractional errors.
The fraction error in $k$ is equal to the sum of the fractional error for each of the terms in the quotient,

ie $\dfrac{\Delta k}{k} = \dfrac{\Delta m}{m} + \dfrac{\Delta g}{g}+\dfrac{\Delta e}{e}$ and it will then be clear to you that the main error in the value of the spring constant is due to the error in the extension.

The errors so far calculated are probably overestimates and a better general estimator of the fractional error is

$\dfrac{\Delta k}{k} = \sqrt{\left (\dfrac{\Delta m}{m} \right)^2+ \left (\dfrac{\Delta g}{g}\right)^2+ \left(\dfrac{\Delta e}{e}\right)^2}$.
However in your case since the fractional error in $mg$ is so much smaller than that in the extension $e$ the simpler formula will suffice.

Comment: I guess that there is no statistical reason to use these 2 methods to evaluate the errors, but I might be wrong. Please, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

### Root Square Sum (RSS)

Try to have a look at the **RSS** (**Root Sum Square**) formula for uncertainty.

You can write every quantity, $y$, as the sum of its mean value $\overline{y} = E[y]$ and its uncertainty $\delta y$, $y = \overline{y} + \delta y$,
and, for small uncertainties you can exploit linearization and all the limits for $\delta y/\overline{y} \ll 0$.

You can write the elastic constant as
$k(m,g,\Delta x) = \dfrac{mg}{\Delta x}$

exploiting:

- "order-0" equation to find the mean value
  $\overline{k} = \dfrac{\overline{m}\overline{g}}{\overline{\Delta x}}$
- "order-1" equation through linearization around the average value to find the difference between the measure and the average value

  $\delta k = \dfrac{\partial k}{\partial m} \delta m +\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial g} \delta g +\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial \Delta x} \delta \Delta x  = \dfrac{k}{\overline{\Delta x}} \delta m + \dfrac{\overline{m}}{\overline{\Delta x}} \delta g - \dfrac{\overline{m}\overline{g}}{\overline{\Delta x}^2} \delta \Delta x$.

You can find the variance of $k$ as a function of the covariance matrix $\sigma_{x_i x_j} = E[\delta x_i \delta x_j]$ of its independent variables $x_i$,

$\sigma_k^2 = E[ \delta k \, \delta k] = E \left[  \displaystyle \sum_{i, j} \delta x_i \dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x_i} \dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x_j} \delta x_j \right] =  \displaystyle \sum_{i, j} \dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x_i} \dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x_j} E \left[ \delta x_i \delta x_j \right]  =  \displaystyle \sum_{i, j} \dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x_j} \sigma_{x_i x_j}$.

**Assuming that the cross-correlation between independent variables is zero**, $\sigma_{x_i x_j} = \sigma^2_{(i)} \delta_{ij}$, you get the RSS formula for uncertainty

$\sigma_k^2 = \displaystyle \sum_i \left( \dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x_i} \right)^2 \sigma^2_{(i)}$

If uncertainty on mass and g can be neglected $\delta m = 0 \, kg$, $\delta g = 0 \, N/m$, you get

$\sigma_k^2 = \left( \dfrac{\overline{m}\overline{g}}{\overline{\Delta x}^2} \right)^2 \sigma_{ \Delta x}^2$.

### Solution of your problem

If you have no uncertainty on the force $F = mg = k \Delta x = 3.43 \, N$, with $\Delta x = \overline{\Delta x} \pm \sigma_{\Delta x} = 0.007 \pm 0.001 \, m$, you get

$\sigma_k^2 = \left( \dfrac{\overline{m}\overline{g}}{\overline{\Delta x}^2} \right)^2 \sigma_{ \Delta x}^2 =
\left( \dfrac{3.43 \,N }{ (0.007 \, m)^2} \right)^2 0.001^2 m^2 = 4900 \left( \dfrac{N}{m} \right)^2 \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \sigma_k = 70 \dfrac{N}{m}$,

with an average value $\overline{k} = \frac{\overline{m}\overline{g}}{\overline{\Delta x}} = 490 \dfrac{N}{m}$, so that you can write the elastic constant as

$k = 490 \pm 70 \dfrac{N}{m}$.

Comment: Good explanation, except that errors never cancel each other out, but adds to each other usually so in whatever sum expression if we encounter subtraction sign,- we change it into plus sign. (order-1 last term). Besides what's the point of adding derivative by $\partial k$ ? Usually error expression is a sum of derivates composed from **independent** variables, but $k$ is not an independent variable.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should emphasize more the RSS method, and less the linearization. Let me edit my answer, that makes it seem that errors cancel out (very poorly written answer, I have to admit). Thanks or your reply

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I missed your question about $k$. It's a typo, it should have been $g$. I edited my answer. Please, take a look if you notice something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it:

1. Trial (calculate with the maximum and minimum values)
2. Use maths: Just apply the same calculation to the uncertainity that you do to the constant.

Suggestion:
Do both and compare the results to check.

Answer (score 0):

As per $k = mgx^{-1}$, absolute error is :

$$ \Delta k = \frac {\partial \left (mgx^{-1} \right) }{\partial m} \Delta m + \frac {\partial \left (mgx^{-1} \right) }{\partial x} \Delta x =  \frac {g}{\overline x} \Delta m + \frac {g~\overline m}{\overline x^2} \Delta x,$$

**Notice**, that in the last term resulting derivative's expression minus sign is automatically changed into plus sign, because whatever roots of error is, they usually tends to add-up in a physical system, but never (or rarely) cancels each other out. So because our goal is to calculate *maximum* possible absolute error, it's good practice to assume that all errors will just add-up and change signs to $+$.

Calculating by this formula spring constant absolute error, substitute in a place of $\overline m,\overline x$ - average object mass and spring displacement values, object on spring mass error $\Delta m$ (you have to know it too, if it's weighted by some scales then it will be scales error) and spring displacement error $\Delta x = 0.001~m$ and you will know how error propagates in expressions.

Comment: All minus signs in derivatives are changed into plus signs, because tendency is that all errors adds-up in a physical system. So plain mathematical reasoning will not help you here.

Comment: Ok, added explanation about sign change.