# Getting different uncertainties for the same variable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics

I was given frequency and wavelength of a wave and asked to find the period and uncertainty in the period.

I first found the uncertainty by doing $$\Delta T = \Delta (1/f)=T\sqrt{(\frac{\Delta 1}{1})^2+(\frac{\Delta f}{f})^2}.$$ However this doesn't look right to me mainly because of the $\Delta 1$. Also the problem gives wavelength and I haven't used that, so I was thinking I should use it somehow.

So the second method I used was to find the speed and its uncertainty, then $$\Delta T = \Delta (\frac{\lambda}{v})=T\sqrt{(\frac{\Delta \lambda}{\lambda})^2+(\frac{\Delta v}{v})^2}.$$

However what is confusing is that I got two different answers for the uncertainty. One of them was $\pm 1\mu s$, the other was $\pm 3\mu s$. I tried calculating again and still got these answers so it can't be a mistake in the calculations.

I am happy to post the actual wavelength and frequency given, but I tried different values for these and still got different uncertainties.

Comment: Try to have a look here about RSS https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/727302

Comment: @basics Thank you. I'm afraid it is too advanced for me to understand.

Comment: ok. I'm giving you a simpler description of the method in an answer

Answer (score 0):

**General rule.** To evaluate the propagation of uncertainties of the dependent variable $z$, that can be expressed as a function of the independent variable $x$, as $z = f(x)$, knowing the uncertainty $\sigma^2_x$ on the variable $x$, you need:

- to evaluate the derivative $\dfrac{d f}{dx}$,
- use the RSS to get $\sigma^2_z = \left(\dfrac{df}{dx}\right)^2 \sigma_x^2$

If the variable $z$ is a function of many variables, you need to evaluate the partial derivatives of $z$, w.r.t. all the variables. As an example, with $z = f(x,y)$, the RSS gives you the formula

$\sigma_z^2 = \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 \sigma_x^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2 \sigma_y^2$.

**Your problem.** When you write $T = \frac{1}{f}$, the period $T$ is a function of only one variable, the frequency $f$ (since 1 is not a variable). Apply the rule above, we evaluate:

- the derivative, $\dfrac{d T}{df} = -\dfrac{1}{f^2}$
- the uncertainty $\sigma_T^2 = \dfrac{1}{f^4} \sigma_f^2$

Comment: We were told that for a division this formula simplifies to $\Delta Q = Q\sqrt{(\frac{\Delta a}{a})^2+(\frac{\Delta b}{b})^2}$ (assuming Q=a/b for example), which is what I used but with a=1, b=f if that makes sense.

Comment: ok, it's right. You don't have to variate 1. 1 is 1, $\Delta 1 = 0$

Comment: 1 is not a variable, so its uncertainty is zero

Comment: Ok so why do I get different answers when I use $T=\frac{\lambda}{v}$ and $T=1/f$? Is it because $T=\frac{\lambda}{v}$ involves different variables than $T=\frac{1}{f}$, almost saying: "The uncertainty in $T$ when measured through $v,\lambda$ is different from its uncertainty when measured only through $f$"?

Comment: probably because you're performing two different kinds of measurement, each one with its own uncertainties: in the first experiment you're measuring $T$, while in the latter you're independently measuring $v$ and $\lambda$. If you perform just one experiment, and try to derive the uncertainties of the quantities you haven't directly measured, these are not independent. In other words, if you perform the second experiment measuring $v$ and $\lambda$ with an experimental procedure with $\Delta v$ and $\Delta \lambda$, the uncertainty $\Delta f$ on $f$ is determined by uncertainty propagation

Comment: In general, you may perform the measurement you like, but you should prefer the one with the lowest uncertainty